# Chef script blocks indefinitely on windows

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

On Windows, after launching the app, the Chef-Solo script blocks indefinitely and returns only after the JVM quits.

Below are the options i've tried :
1. Used the "batch" resource that's supposed to work like "bash". But when Chef runs it - windows complains with "This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running..." etc.
2. i used the "execute" resource and used "start java" as

```
execute "start" do
    command "start java ...."
end
```

and that is where im able to run the app, but the chef script gets stuck.

There's not much documentation around on this issue.

Anyone knows the fix for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: What is the bitness of the Java installation?

Comment: @HenryFinucane I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise with Java 6.

Comment: I feel like I had a thought about this, but it's been over a year...